# Concept to disable all background content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here I am using jquery dialog box but I have to disable my background content so that user should not able to click on any button or not able to select anything.

But how to do it.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `modal: true` **option** to your `dialog`,

```
$(function() {
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
       modal: true
   });
});
```

Read **[dialog/#modal](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal)**

Answer (score 3):

Set `modal: true` on the dialog:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the built in [`modal`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal) option.

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
     modal: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
     modal: true
});
```